# Replace single quote to double through ansible

Tags: sed, ansible

I am trying to replace single quotes to double through ansible using sed command

```
- name: Remove single quotes from ios paths
  shell: sed 's/'\''/"/g "/opt/mob/{{ item.key }}/sitefile"
  with_items:
     - "{{ lookup('dict', ogs) }}"
```

from a file called sitefile with following content

```
{
  "paths": ['/myfolder/*', '/open/folder*']
}
```

to change it to

```
{
  "paths": ["/myfolder/*", "/open/folder*"]
}
```

But it doesn't do anything.

above variables are defined in group vars and using j2 template to compile this file

```
app_paths: 
       - /myfolder/*
       - /open/folder*
```

Comment: I wonder what program is generating the file? They should be generated correctly from the beginning instead of your post-processing. Does it even handle escaped quotes correctly? I think it's doing more harm than good.

Comment: Have you tried a simpler replacement, like changing 'o' to 'x'?

Comment: you need to use `-i` flag with `sed` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patterns can be simplified in [Single-Quoted Style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097). Quoting:

> "*The single-quoted style is specified by surrounding “'” indicators. Therefore, within a single-quoted scalar, such characters **need to be repeated**. This is the only form of escaping performed in single-quoted scalars. In particular, the “\” and “"” characters may be freely used."*

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat sitefile 
{
  "paths": ['/myfolder/*', '/open/folder*']
  }
```

The task below does the replacements

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: sitefile
        regexp: ''''
        replace: '"'
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat sitefile 
{
  "paths": ["/myfolder/*", "/open/folder*"]
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use the replace module for that. And put the special characters in jinja2 strings in this way:

```
  - name: replace
    replace:
      path: "/opt/mob/{{ item.key }}/sitefile"
      regexp: "{{ \"'\" }}"
      replace: "{{ '\"' }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ lookup('dict', ogs) }}"
```

Links:

- https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/replace_module.html